# SQL getting all products linked to a specific transactionId

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm a newbie in SQL and I'm stuck. I wish you could help me...
I'm using BigQuery to look informations on my table.
I want to have a table with all transactionId that have at least 1 productSKU == to "0185300".
I can get the dataset with all rows that have productsSKU equal to "0185300" but then I don't have the other products linked to that transactionId ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the list of affected transactions and use that as a filter for the main query, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table>
WHERE transactionId IN (
   SELECT transactionId 
   FROM <table> 
   WHERE productSKU = '0185300'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct transactionId from `project.dataset.table`
where productSKU = '0185300'
```